# iPhone X: Is there an easy way to detect if an user is watching on the screen?

Tags: ios, iphone-x

I did a little research and found out that I should start here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arfacetrackingconfiguration

It's a little bit tricky because I don't own an iPhone X myself and before I do a lot of unnecessary inconvenience I just want to ask if there is an easy way or maybe someone who had the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the answer by trickster is not entirely true. ARKit does track your eyes (just incase anyone else was misled by the answer).

If you really had to do this, a way you could do this is by:
-checking ARAnchors for a FaceAnchor
-Use FaceAnchor.isTracked - this will tell if if the users face is in view.
-if above is true - you can use the transform for the head anchor to check if the head is pointing towards the screen
-If you need even more accuracy you can check the eyes are open and the angle of the eyes using the blendweights.

I think it would definitely be possible to do this - whether it is easy or not depends on your exact definition of "watching the screen" and your maths skills.

Answer (score 0):

ARKit face tracking does not track eyes, only the position of the head and shape/expression of the face. Apple does perform gaze tracking / attention detection in Face ID, but there’s no external developer API for such.